# How to maintain data in the clipboard after setting it in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, clipboard

I'm trying to set the Text value of the Clipboard to the value of a string variable in a WPF application on .NET 4.7.2.  If I debug the application and stop the execution right after the clipboard value has been saved then the value is there in clipboard and I can paste it as expected.  If I continue execution then the value is wiped of sorts.  For example, this is code that I can use to test with:

```
public void CopyToClipboard()
{
    string temp = "test\ntest\ntest";
    System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText(temp);
}
```

As you can see there are three lines that should be pasted.  When I stop execution right after saving to the clipboard I will see an output like so:

```
test
test
test
```

If I continue execution (by hitting F5 or the "Continue" button in Visual Studio) then when I paste I get three lines of '\t' tabs.  So, my three lines still exist, but the text has been erased.

Can anyone help me to get this resolved.  What is causing me to loose the data in the clipboard?

Comment: I dont believe the text has been erased, the proper word would be, "sanitized". From MS site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.clipboard?view=netframework-4.8: "A non-Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) full trust application can examine the ApplicationTrust format on the clipboard and sanitize the XAML if appropriate."

Comment: I agree, I think that this is what is happening since I still have the lines available.  So, the question is, how do I overcome this issue so that I can paste the data as it is copied?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a quick Linqpad script that just consists of the following line:

`System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText("Hello");`

And my clipboard is successfully set to "Hello" and stays that way after the program exits. Is there something else in your application that is modifying the clipboard?

Comment: I checked and nothing else is updating the clipboard.  My application is a WPF application, so that handles the clipboard a little differently I suppose.  I think @Jawad is closest to the answer.  I think that the text is getting sanitized, but I don't know how to get the text to remain without being sanitized when I paste it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard.settext?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_Clipboard_SetText_System_String_

```
public String SwapClipboardHtmlText(String replacementHtmlText)
{
    String returnHtmlText = null;
    if (Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Html))
    {
        returnHtmlText = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html);
        Clipboard.SetText(replacementHtmlText, TextDataFormat.Html);
    }
    return returnHtmlText;
}
```

> The Clipboard class can only be used in threads set to single thread
>   apartment (STA) mode. To use this class, ensure that your Main method
>   is marked with the STAThreadAttribute attribute.

Comment: Yeah, I checked and the Main method has the STAThreadAttribute on it.  I think the biggest issue is that this is a WPF application.